# How to create user on firebase from actions.google.com Streamlined Identity Flows

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-openid, actions-on-google

I am in the process of creating a google assistant for a firebase app. In the process, I want to implement the [Streamlined Identity Flows](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow) and create the users on my firebase application when they provide consent through the flow.

But the catch is, I should be creating the firebase user with

```
// Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);

// Sign in with credential from the Google user.
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(err) {...});
```

But for this I would need the id_token which I will not be getting from the assretion flow. All I get from assertion flow is the unique id of the google user.

To get id_token, seems I need to pass in the scopes as `openid email profile`. Gone through the [Openid Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode) but couldn't gather whether I should implement this flow in the `token` endpoint? if so what will be the intents in such flow?

Comment: If I receive the `id_token` right from the assertion flow, it makes more sense because user has approved my app to access his google account already! But I don't see this coming as per the documentation (section: Create new accounts from JWT assertions) in https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NodeJS jsonwebtoken library to decode the provided ID token, as documented in the [Assertion Flows page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/preview/oauth2-assertion-flow), to get the email address and then call

> adminSDK.auth().getUserByEmail()

or

> createUser()

as appropriate that'll create users for you